# How can I filter a DataFrame based on a specific Pattern in R?

Tags: r, string, dplyr

I have a DataFrame like this:

```
Column_A    Column_Text
  A            hello world
  A            hi world
  B            go r
  C            dplyr
```

In addition, I have a list, with **string patterns**

```
String_Patterns = c('world', 'go')
```

I want to keep the rows, where **Column_Text** is containing the pattern of "**String_Patterns**".

I found some solutions on stackoverflow, however they are not totally what I want:

```
> grepl("world", df$Column_Text, fixed = FALSE) 
  # This will lead to TRUE/FALSE (not a subset), and I can only add a pattern one-by-one, for example:
> grepl(c("world", "go"), df$COlumn_Text, fixed = FALSE) # is not working...
```

Desired output:

```
Column_A     Column_Text
   A           hello world  #contains pattern world
   A           hi world     #contains pattern world
   B           go r         #contains pattern go
```

Many thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can `paste` to create the pattern for `subset`ting

```
subset(df, grepl(paste(String_Patterns, collapse= "|"), Column_Text))
```

Comment: Thanks @akrun. However, I think you miss an ending ")". When adding that, I receive the error message: "Error in grepl..... argument "x" is missing, with no default". Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The `tidyverse` equivalent of akruns answer would use `filter` instead of `subset`, `str_detect` instead of `grepl` and `str_c` instead of `paste`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

data %>% 
  filter(str_detect(Column_Text, str_c(String_Patterns, collapse = "|")))
```